# invalid argument Error in python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

The below python code is running in my windows 7(32 bit) machine. But it showing following error in windows 7 (64 bit) machine,

```
proc.stdin.write('%d\n' % i)
invalid argument
```

Code:

```
import subprocess

print 'One line at a time:'
proc = subprocess.Popen('python repeater.py', 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       )
for i in range(10):
    proc.stdin.write('%d\n' % i)
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print output.rstrip()
remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
print remainder

print
print 'All output at once:'
proc = subprocess.Popen('python repeater.py', 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
for i in range(10):
    proc.stdin.write('%d\n' % i)

output = proc.communicate()[0]
print output
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your windows firewall! Ensure that it is not blocking pipes. Although I guess you should have got some permission error in that case. But still worth a try!

Comment: firewall is already turned off and i have full permission...